# Pre-populate form fields from the html table's row on which it is clicked.(all this is supposed to happen on jsp)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to use jquery or  javascript to populate form fields with the row elements which is chosen by clicking the row.
I tried the solution found on the stackoverflow to a similar question.I am a newbie ,please bear with me.**(http://jsbin.com/rotuni/2/edit)**.But I tried many times.It is not working as it is supposed to be.

```
 //html part containing the form fields which is to be pre-populated.
 <body>
<form class="data-form">
<label>Value1<input class="value1" /></label>
<label>Value2<input class="value2" /></label>
<label>Value3<input class="value3" /></label>
<label>Value4<input class="value4" /></label>
</form>

  <table class="data-table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
            <th>value3</th>
            <th>value4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
 </body>
```

js part

```
$(function() {

  var tableData = [
    {
      value1: "row1-v1",
      value2: "row1-v2",
      value3: "row1-v3",
      value4: "row1-v4"
    }, {
      value1: "row2-v1",
      value2: "row2-v2",
      value3: "row2-v3",
      value4: "row2-v4"
    }
  ];

  var rows = $.map(tableData, function(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append($('<td class="class1"></td>').html(rowData.value1));
    row.append($('<td class="class2"></td>').html(rowData.value2));
    row.append($('<td class="class3"></td>').html(rowData.value3));
    row.append($('<td class="class4"></td>').html(rowData.value4));

    row.on("click", function() {
      fillForm(rowData);
    });

    return row;
  });

  $(".data-table").append(rows);

  function fillForm(rowData) {
    var form = $(".data-form");

    form.find("input.value1").val(rowData.value1);
    form.find("input.value2").val(rowData.value2);
    form.find("input.value3").val(rowData.value3);
    form.find("input.value4").val(rowData.value4);
  }
});
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I am not able to populate the table.OUTPUT: On the html page only the HEADING appears i.e. >value1 >value2 >value3 >value4

Comment: Not able to perform the click on the row(which is not there) and populate form fields.Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always use these for js and ui part.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing import script for using the jquery.You will have to import the jquery.min.js for using jquery functions.Import the following script and it would work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```